# unisharp/laravel-ckeditor on Laravel 8+ cannot install package

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to install ckeditor on my Laravel 8+ project, but can't.
I have the errors:

Problem 1:

- Root composer.json requires unisharp/laravel-ckeditor 4.7.2 -> satisfiable by unisharp/laravel-ckeditor[4.7.2].
- unisharp/laravel-ckeditor 4.7.2 requires illuminate/support ~5.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but it conflicts with another require.

[this is the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB3C7.png)

I've tried install version 4.7.2 and 5.0, but that still not working.

Is someone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The command `composer require ckeditor/ckeditor` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`unisharp/laravel-ckeditor` has seen it's latest release in Nov 2017, more than three years ago. As the error message tells you: this package is not compatible with current versions of Laravel. Either downgrade Laravel to v5 (not recommended), search for another package providing such functionality, or fork the package to provide the neccessary updates.

Comment: I found a solution on github, which says that I need to copy the files to the project directory and everything should work.
But it didn't help.
Perhaps there is an option to copy files or part of the files by hand into a project folder?

Comment: "It didn't help" is pretty broad. But yes, installing by hand is possible. That's how other people did it, according to the issue tracker of that project

Comment: Yes, I understand.

Comment: I added everything to the  'public/ckeditor' folder and specified id and name in the form where I put data but it didn't work. I think that not all files need to be added or I should added it in some other directory. I don't understand yet how folders are organized and access from them in Laravel to different files.

Comment: "It didn't work" is still broad, what does that mean? You should open a new question containing all information about that

Comment: By the way, there are no errors, the editor didn't displayed, that's all.

Comment: Also, there's a fork of the initial package at https://github.com/dev-techguy/laravel-ckeditor - so maybe you give that a try?

Comment: If the editor is not displayed, I would assume that you haven't added the neccessary JS parts to load the JS code and initialize the editor on the fields

Answer (score 0):

To install ckeditor on Laravel 8+ project.
If you already have npm installed then use this line:

```
$ npm install ckeditor4
```

Then execute the following command:

```
$ npm update
```

Answer (score 0):

i ran in to the same problem using`

`composer require unisharp/laravel-ckeditor`

then i used
`$ composer require ckeditor/ckeditor`
and it solved it